# What am I doing wrong with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm currently having trouble with a machine learning project in Tensorflow. The input to the neural network is a 26x1 list of numbers, and the desired output is a 5x16 binary array.

I am training with this data. Here is my [testing sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stockfish8/PolySolver/master/testing_sample.csv) and my [training sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stockfish8/PolySolver/master/training_sample.csv). You can download it from Git by right clicking on the webpage and clicking 'Save as'.

Also, the full code is [here](https://github.com/stockfish8/PolySolver/blob/master/MachineLearningTest.py) just so that you don't have to copy and paste mutiple times from StackOverflow.

I will go through my code. I don't think it's necessary to understand what everything does in there, but I have heavily annotated my thought process anyways. The main focus of the question is whether I'm doing the machine learning correctly in Tensorflow.

```
'''Imports'''
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

''' Here we unpack the .csv files. I have chosen to put their contents 
into lists. Do let me know if there exists a more efficient method. '''

distribution_train = []
probs_train = []
distribution_test = []
probs_test = []

with open('training_sample.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        distribution_train.append(row[0])
        probs_train.append(row[1])

with open('testing_sample.csv') as csv_file_1:
    csv_reader_1 = csv.reader(csv_file_1, delimiter= ',')

    for row in csv_reader_1:
        distribution_test.append(row[0])
        probs_test.append(row[1])


'''Get rid of the titles in the training_sample.csv file.'''
distribution_train.pop(0)
probs_train.pop(0)
```

Our data has been extracted from the .csv file and stored in lists, but the numbers exists as strings for some reason. So I will define a function that extracts out all the numbers.

```
'''For some reason everything in my csv file is stored as strings. Or 
maybe it's just because of the way I have unpacked it. The below function 
is to convert it into floats so that TF can work with it. 
It's crude, but it locates all the numbers and appends them to a list, 
which then gets appended to a giant list called f.'''

def num_converter_flatten(csv_list):
    f = []
    for j in range(len(csv_list)):
        append_this = []
        for i in csv_list[j]:
            if i == '1' or i == '2' or i == '3' or i == '4' or i == '5' or i == '6' or i == '7' or i == '8' or i =='9' or i =='0':
                append_this.append(float(i))
        f.append((append_this))

    return f

'''Basically, this line is to convert the distribution_train and 
probs_train which are currently strings
into numbers. And we normalize the training data.'''
x_train = num_converter_flatten(distribution_train)
y_train = num_converter_flatten(probs_train)
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
```

Now we reshape it into tensors and make sure that they have the same float.

```
'''This line we reshape x_train and y_train into tensors. The convertion 
to float 32 is also necessary as I realised that A and B are different 
floats for some reason.'''

A = tf.reshape(x_train, [-1,1*26])
B = tf.reshape(y_train, [-1,1*80])
A = tf.dtypes.cast(A, dtype = tf.float32)
B = tf.dtypes.cast(B, dtype = tf.float32)

'''Doing the same thing to x_test and y_test'''

x_test = num_converter_flatten(distribution_test)
y_test = num_converter_flatten(probs_test)
C = tf.reshape(x_test, [-1,1*26])
D = tf.reshape(y_test, [-1,1*80])
C = tf.dtypes.cast(C, dtype = tf.float32)
D = tf.dtypes.cast(D, dtype = tf.float32)
```

Now we train our model.

```
'''Model starts from here'''

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

'''I'm not too sure if relu is the right activation function to use here. 
I've tried different activation functions, but all run into the same 
problem described below.'''

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(180, activation=keras.activations.relu, input_shape=(26,)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2080, activation=keras.activations.relu))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(180, activation=keras.activations.relu))

'''I'm making the final layer 80 because I want TF to output the size of 
the 'probs' list in the csv file'''

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(80, activation=keras.activations.softplus))

'''Again I'm not sure if softplus is the best to use here. I've also 
tested a number of activation functions for the last layer, and it also 
runs to the same problem.'''

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(A,B, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=16)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(C,D, steps = 128)
print (val_loss, val_acc)


'''Just saving the model'''
model.save('epic_equation_model_try1')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('epic_equation_model_try1')
predictions = new_model.predict(C, steps = 1)
```

Here's the main problem. If you run the model (for 2 epochs), the accuracy goes up but after that it goes down, then up again. Eventually, if you run it for several more epochs, it peaks it 0.6221. Why does it peak at this number? Again, this is not unique to the softplus activation. Several other activation functions I have tested like tanh or softmax or sigmoid does the same thing. I'm new to machine learning, but I don't think that the accruacy should be peaking at such a consistent and low number.

Secondly, if I ask my model to predict something, it gives me a list of very small numbers. So for instance, if I wanted my model to predict the 1st data sample of my testing_sample.csv, I would do this:

```
for i in range(1):
    x = np.array(predictions[i]).reshape(5,16)
    print (x)
```

And I would get something like this...

```
[[0.00000014 0.00000065 0.0000007  0.00000031 0.00000069 0.00000003
0.00000073 0.00000009 0.00000001 0.00000095 0.00000215 0.00000045
0.00000155 0.00000274 0.00000057 0.00053975]
[0.00000016 0.00000011 0.00000021 0.00000006 0.00000012 0.00000022
0.00000002 0.00000005 0.00000019 0.00000002 0.00000087 0.00000465
0.00000238 0.00000009 0.00003278 0.00001788]
[0.00000002 0.00000001 0.00000046 0.00000131 0.00000072 0.00000006
0.00000005 0.00000001 0.00000001 0.0000003  0.0000005  0.00000016
0.00000465 0.00000226 0.00000083 0.00002015]
[0.00000005 0.0000004  0.00000001 0.00000032 0.00000008 0.00000061
0.00000107 0.00000015 0.00000013 0.00000014 0.00000012 0.00000037
0.00000334 0.00000016 0.00000057 0.00018404]
[0.00000044 0.00000038 0.00000095 0.00000013 0.0000002  0.00000006
0.00000019 0.00000087 0.00000095 0.00000016 0.00000513 0.00000095
0.00000846 0.0000534  0.00000049 0.00000429]]
```

Basically an ugly looking matrix of 16x5. It is clear that some numbers are clearly bigger than the others especially if you disable `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` at the top. I'm not sure what to make of these numbers. Currently, I'm assuming that the bigger numbers means that the machine is more confident that it will be a 1.

Currently, this is what I'm doing to convert this output matrix into binary. But it's an rather arbitrary way of doing it.

```
'''This tests for only the first prediction. If you wwant to see more 
predictions, change the range.'''
for i in range(1):
    MUTI = 500000
    x = np.array(predictions[i]).reshape(5,16)
    # print (x)
    PX = MUTI*x
    PX = np.round(PX, 2)
    PX[PX<0.1] = 0
    PX[PX>0.1] = 1
    PX[PX==0.1] = 1
    print (PX)
```

So what am I doing wrong here? The best option is to have the output matrix correspond to 0s and 1s, something like [0.999998, 0.000002, 0.000003, 0.099995...], but so far I found no function in Tensorflow that allows me to do this.

Also, am I doing the machine learning procedure correctly? I feel like the accuracy shouldn't be peaking at 0.6221 for all activation functions.

EDIT: After changing the function in the last layer to sigmoid:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(80, activation=keras.activations.sigmoid))
```

This is how the model is training now.

```
 # Model Training
 1/16 [>.............................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.4845
 2/16 [==>...........................] - ETA: 20s - loss: 0.6919 - acc: 0.5277
 3/16 [====>.........................] - ETA: 18s - loss: 0.6905 - acc: 0.5470
 4/16 [======>.......................] - ETA: 15s - loss: 0.6889 - acc: 0.5577
 5/16 [========>.....................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.6871 - acc: 0.5654
 6/16 [==========>...................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.6851 - acc: 0.5720
 7/16 [============>.................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.6831 - acc: 0.5769
 8/16 [==============>...............] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.6813 - acc: 0.5813 
 9/16 [===============>..............] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.6799 - acc: 0.5851
 10/16 [=================>............] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.6787 - acc: 0.5883
 11/16 [===================>..........] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.6776 - acc: 0.5912
 12/16 [=====================>........] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6766 - acc: 0.5936
 13/16 [=======================>......] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.6756 - acc: 0.5957
 14/16 [=========================>....] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6746 - acc: 0.5975
 15/16 [===========================>..] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6738 - acc: 0.5991
 16/16 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.6731 - acc: 0.6005
Epoch 2/2

1/16 [>.............................] - ETA: 16s - loss: 0.6626 - acc: 0.6221
2/16 [==>...........................] - ETA: 15s - loss: 0.6625 - acc: 0.6221
3/16 [====>.........................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.6624 - acc: 0.6221
4/16 [======>.......................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.6623 - acc: 0.6221
5/16 [========>.....................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.6622 - acc: 0.6221
6/16 [==========>...................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.6621 - acc: 0.6221
7/16 [============>.................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.6621 - acc: 0.6221
8/16 [==============>...............] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.6621 - acc: 0.6221 
9/16 [===============>..............] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.6621 - acc: 0.6221
10/16 [=================>............] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.6621 - acc: 0.6221
11/16 [===================>..........] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6620 - acc: 0.6221
12/16 [=====================>........] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6620 - acc: 0.6221
13/16 [=======================>......] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.6620 - acc: 0.6221
14/16 [=========================>....] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6620 - acc: 0.6221
15/16 [===========================>..] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6619 - acc: 0.6221
16/16 [==============================] - 18s 1s/step - loss: 0.6619 - acc: 0.6221

# Testing Sample
1/128 [..............................] - ETA: 11s
6/128 [>.............................] - ETA: 3s 
10/128 [=>............................] - ETA: 2s
14/128 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2s
19/128 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1s
23/128 [====>.........................] - ETA: 1s
27/128 [=====>........................] - ETA: 1s
32/128 [======>.......................] - ETA: 1s
36/128 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1s
41/128 [========>.....................] - ETA: 1s
45/128 [=========>....................] - ETA: 1s
50/128 [==========>...................] - ETA: 1s
54/128 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1s
59/128 [============>.................] - ETA: 1s
63/128 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s
67/128 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s
72/128 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s
76/128 [================>.............] - ETA: 0s
81/128 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s
84/128 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s
88/128 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s
92/128 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s
96/128 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s
101/128 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s
105/128 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s
109/128 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s
112/128 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s
116/128 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
120/128 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
124/128 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s
128/128 [==============================] - 2s 15ms/step
# Val loss, val acc
3.21346378326416 0.6113420724868774
# Model prediction 
[0.07243679 0.06086067 0.17687203 0.0424496  0.04154298]
[[3.17100697e-04 1.11687055e-04 1.74964574e-04 6.10632123e-05
9.15286364e-05 5.74094338e-05 1.06784762e-04 9.21065075e-05
3.97201220e-04 6.81500824e-05 2.94565433e-03 1.35827821e-03
2.81211367e-04 1.00520747e-02 6.01871812e-04 5.57196997e-02]
[4.75579909e-05 1.06101972e-04 6.00069507e-05 4.96198081e-05
1.41731420e-04 8.79359577e-05 7.46832447e-05 4.33949099e-05
6.03557055e-05 7.12051406e-05 8.45988281e-04 2.34248699e-03
2.74868420e-04 1.51112420e-03 7.97806482e-04 5.43457977e-02]
[1.06174128e-04 6.14731325e-05 2.77487037e-04 9.75391740e-05
6.97174910e-05 1.57534625e-04 1.94240944e-04 7.85565353e-05
8.36232939e-05 4.36835981e-05 4.04849125e-04 6.86666509e-03
3.01186665e-04 3.41302366e-04 2.24954495e-03 1.65538445e-01]
[4.85532328e-05 5.30333891e-05 1.46693186e-04 2.40156965e-04
6.14130186e-05 6.84155602e-05 1.68141501e-04 9.09807641e-05
2.58948799e-04 6.01471947e-05 1.68107694e-03 8.52260040e-04
1.04383787e-03 4.75410791e-03 4.93220054e-04 3.24286185e-02]
[2.70062083e-05 1.19853627e-04 2.31390568e-05 4.41022166e-05
6.90615489e-05 2.53524253e-04 1.09332977e-04 7.17278526e-05
1.98521622e-04 3.77545693e-05 1.86053314e-03 2.42721115e-04
1.85445603e-03 1.16664183e-03 1.00720196e-03 3.44574042e-02]]
```

The model is still producing values close of zeros and it's accuracy is still peaking at 0.6221. Should I set a threshold for this to make it binary?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the activation at the output layer to sigmoid, which will give you values in the [0, 1] range. You can then apply threshold to get binary values.

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(80, activation=keras.activations.sigmoid))
```

Note that keras computes binary accuracy by thresholding the outputs at 0.5, and it will compute accuracy of each output separately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've added an edit to my question. The model is still basically predicting values close to 0 when it should be predicting close to 0 and 1. Should I just add a threshold for this or is there a way for the model to predict values closer to 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to predict from a (1,26) (real valued ?) matrix a 5 *16 binary matrix.

- The first thing you should always check is if your training accuracy and training losses increases resp decreases with the nbr of epochs or not ? A neural network should always be able to overfit !

  - If you're training loss is not decreasing, there is a problem with your network:
- Since you should only get binary values in the output layer, use an activation function that outputs data between [0, 1] a sigmoid for example. These values will be used to calculate the loss.
- Since you want to predict binary values you should then condition the output, if the output > threshold --> 1 otherwise 0. I'm more used to Tensorflow than keras, so i'm not sure how does keras calculate accuracy when the outputs are numbers... Try to change the metric to a custom one such as :

```
    import keras.backend as K
    from keras.metrics import binary_accuracy
    def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
        threshold =0.5
        thresholded_values = K.greater(y_pred, threshold)
        return binary_accuracy(y_true, thresholded_values)
```

PS i did not test the code maybe you need to transform  boolean tensor to a real valued one...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've added an edit to my question. The model is still basically predicting values close to 0 when it should be predicting close to 0 and 1. Should I just add a threshold for this or is there a way for the model to predict values closer to 0 and 1?